# SSL connection fails to Datapusher app through port 8800, with NGINX reverse proxy to Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, openssl, ckan

I am installing the [datapusher](https://github.com/ckan/datapusher) service for [CKAN](https://github.com/ckan/ckan).
CKAN has been configured to use an NGINX reverse proxy that routes client requests, following [instructions here](https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2/wiki/Starting-CKAN-over-HTTPs-using-Apache-and-Nginx). SSL certificate is installed and configured in NGINX. 
When trying to use the datapusher app to upload a file, it fails and Apache log gives this error:

```
Mon Apr 03 13:49:10.979179 2017] [:error] [pid 15468] 2017-04-03 13:49:10,979 CRITI [ckanext.datapusher.plugin] {'status_code': 403, 'message': 'An Error occurred while sending the job: 403 Client Error: Forbidden', 'details': u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\\n<html><head>\\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\\n</head><body>\\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\\n<p>You don\\'t have permission to access /job\\non this server.</p>\\n<hr>\\n<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 8800</address>\\n</body></html>\\n'}
```

When testing access to the datapusher's 8800 port through openssl this is the output:

```
[Mon Apr 03 13:49:10.981049 2017] [:error] [pid 15468] [remote 127.0.0.1:6855] Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: notify() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) 
open:/etc/ckan> openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8800
CONNECTED(00000003)
140385459791520:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 275 bytes
```

The datapusher docs give a workaround for bypassing SSL [here](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/using.html#configuring-ssl-verification), using the `SSL_Verify` config. I tried this and there was no change.

I think that I need to either:
1. Force the nginx reverse proxy to allow SSL connections through port 8800 (in addition to 443). Or...
2. Configure ckan/datapusher/apache/nginx to bypass SSL/https on port 880.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 403 error is at the point that CKAN sends a request to DataPusher to ask it to load a particular resource. DataPusher is running on Apache only and thus is on HTTP (not HTTPS) so there should be no issue with SSL. Check your CKAN config is the default:

```
ckan.datapusher.url = http://127.0.0.1:8800/
```

DataPusher's SSL_VERIFY setting is for a later request - when datapusher makes a request to CKAN at ckan.site_url, which for you will go via nginx over HTTPS. You may need this setting, depending on whether the SSL in your python is compatible. Reading the code it suggests you need quotes and make sure the key is all caps. i.e. in your datapusher_settings.py:

```
SSL_VERIFY = 'False'
```

Comment: Thanks. I've now tried every combination of those settings, and still getting the same error.